# php72 dynamic url routing with front controller via entry point standard not working Google App Engine [GAE]

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app.yaml, front-controller

My dynamic URL is not reading on my website on GAE, cause I want to use the incoming GET to query my database.

As it stands, Php72 does not allowing routing from app.yaml must be from front controller via entry point which the default is publichtml/index.php or index.php.

I changed mine to worker.php. The listing.php URL below is the dynamic that I mean listing/random-dynamic-text-here while index.php and about.php is static pages.

NB: the page index.php and about.php and listing.php is called and displayed on the browser, but i cannot get the content of $_GET["linkcheck"]; in listing.php. Refer below.

app.yaml

```
runtime: php72

runtime_config:
  document_root:
  
handlers:

- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301

entrypoint:
  serve worker.php
```

//entry point worker.php

```
<?php 
ini_set('allow_url_fopen',1);
switch (@parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path']){
  case '/':
      require 'index.php';
      break;
  case '/index':
      require 'index.php';
      break;
  case '/index.php':
      require 'index.php';
      break;
  case '/about':
      require 'about.php';
      break;
  case '/about.php':
      require 'about.php';
      break;
  case '/listing':
      require 'listing.php';
      break;
  case '/listing.php':
      require 'listing.php';
      break;
  case '/listing/':
      require 'listing.php/';
      break;
  case '/listing.php/':
      require 'listing.php/';
      break;
  default:
      http_response_code(404);
      header("Location: https://www.example.com/404");
      exit();
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Home</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

about.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>About</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>About</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Where listing.php below is the file/page where I am expecting $_GET["linkcheck"];

listing.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Listing</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><?php $cool = $_GET["linkcheck"]; echo $cool; ?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you can only change the setting of `allow_url_fopen` from an INI file as it is set to `PHP_INI_SYSTEM`

Comment: @riggsfolly Thank you for your answer, lease kindly expantiate

Comment: I deployed your code on app engine and got it working as it is,  just by calling:  `<GAE_URL>/listing.php?linkcheck=a`  I got the dynamic behavior, what are you willing to get?

Comment: @JoséSoní thanks for your answer, i want a url rewrite sort of like .htaccess something like listing/dynamic-rewrite-text-example

Comment: to be clear you want to have `.../listing/DYNAMIC_TEXT` and print DYNAMIC_TEXT right?

Comment: @JoséSoní yes yes yes and yes, that what i want to achieve and it keeps redirecting to 404 page, I want to grab DYNAMIC_TEXT as $_GET[linkcheck];

Comment: @JoséSoní are you there.

Comment: @JoséSoní 
thanks for your answer, it worked, to a little expand I so lets say i have .../listing/DYNAMIC_TEXT/ANOTHER_DYNAMIC_TEXT i should edit worker to case (preg_match('/listing.*/.*/', $path) ? true : false) : require 'listing.php'; break; and listing would be something like $cool = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$cool_one = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];          echo $cool; echo $cool_one

Comment: @JoséSoní you are right, it sends a fatal error, so if i want to get  .../listing/DYNAMIC_TEXT/ANOTHER_DYNAMIC_TEXT, i would so $_SEVER["REQUEST_URI"]; and split the URL into two places, before and after the slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you need to modify two of your files:

**worker.php**

```
<?php 
ini_set('allow_url_fopen',1);
$path = @parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path'];
switch ($path){
  case '/':
      require 'index.php';
      break;
  case '/index':
      require 'index.php';
      break;
  case '/index.php':
      require 'index.php';
      break;
  case '/about':
      require 'about.php';
      break;
  case '/about.php':
      require 'about.php';
      break;
  case '/listing':
      require 'listing.php';
      break;
  case '/listing.php':
      require 'listing.php';
      break;
  case '/listing/':
      require 'listing.php';
      break;
  case   (preg_match('/listing.*/', $path) ? true : false) :
      require 'listing.php';
      break;
   default:
      http_response_code(404);
      header("Location: https://www.example.com/404");
      exit();
}
?>
```

The difference here is to match regular expression that starts with `/listing` and send it to the listing Script.

The second modification is on listing to have this line:

`<h1><?php $cool = $_GET["linkcheck"]; echo $cool; ?></h1>`

replaced by this one:

`<h1><?php $cool = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; echo $cool; ?></h1>`

I tested it and it works now as espected.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I so lets say i have .../listing/DYNAMIC_TEXT/ANOTHER_DYNAMIC_TEXT i should edit worker to   case   (preg_match('/listing.*/.*/', $path) ? true : false) :
      require 'listing.php';
      break;

Comment: it already accepts all this, basically what it does is that after `/listing` its accepting whatever you put

Comment: you are right, it sends a fatal error, so if i want to get  .../listing/DYNAMIC_TEXT/ANOTHER_DYNAMIC_TEXT, i would so $_SEVER["REQUEST_URI"]; and split the URL into two places, before and after the slash.